# echo php values in table - strange behaviour, not all values are shown

Tags: php, functions, table

I am currently despairing on a for me very strange behaviour when echoing php values to html table cells.

I simply want to loop through an array and print out the values into a table but only some information is shown under special conditions.

Outside of the table the values are shown.

```
<?php

foreach ($mpbs_overview_tab4_bookings as $tab4_arr) {
 echo "<tr>";
  $tab4startDate = new DateTime($tab4_arr->starttime);
  $tab4endDate = new DateTime($tab4_arr->endtime);
  echo '<td>' . $tab4startDate->format('d.m.Y H:i') .'</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $tab4endDate->format('d.m.Y') .'</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $tab4_arr->username .'</td>';
 echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Using this code, `$tab4startDate->format('d.m.Y H:i')` is shown, `$tab4endDate->format('d.m.Y')` not. Adding `H:i` to `$tab4endDate`s format results to the fact, that it is shown again.

`$tab4_arr->username` is also not shown. 
If I change  content to

```
echo "<td>";
 echo $tab4startDate->format('d.m.Y H:i');
 echo $tab4_arr->username;
echo "</td>";
```

for testing purposes, also the username is visible...

Has anybody an idea, what I am doing wrong?

This is my array:

```
{"id":"185","starttime":"2017-11-26 00:00:00","endtime":"2017-11-29 00:00:00","username":"lsgit"},
{"id":"186","starttime":"2017-11-26 00:00:00","endtime":"2017-11-29 00:00:00","username":"lsgit"},
{"id":"187","starttime":"2017-11-19 00:00:00","endtime":"2017-11-22 00:00:00","username":"lsgit"},
{"id":"188","starttime":"2017-11-30 00:00:00","endtime":"2017-12-03 00:00:00","username":"lsgit"},
{"id":"189","starttime":"2017-12-05 00:00:00","endtime":"2017-12-08 00:00:00","username":"lsgit"},
{"id":"190","starttime":"2017-12-05 00:00:00","endtime":"2017-12-08 00:00:00","username":"lsgit"},
{"id":"191","starttime":"2017-12-05 00:00:00","endtime":"2017-12-08 00:00:00","username":"lsgit"}
```

Comment: add your array to your question

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here `echo '<td>' . $tab4_arr->username; .'</td>';`

Remove the **;**

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I removed the semicolon. I accidentally added it, as I changed my code. But that was not the reason... Still not working.

Comment: Its working fine for me without the semicolon https://eval.in/902320

Answer (score 0):

Elements of `$mpbs_overview_tab4_bookings` array are json encoded. Your code should be:

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
foreach ($mpbs_overview_tab4_bookings as $tab4_arr) {
  $tab4_arr = json_decode($tab4_arr);
  echo '<tr>';
  $tab4startDate = new DateTime($tab4_arr->starttime);
  $tab4endDate = new DateTime($tab4_arr->endtime);
  echo '<td>' . $tab4startDate->format('d.m.Y H:i') .'</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $tab4endDate->format('d.m.Y') .'</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $tab4_arr->username .'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm really embarrassed about that now, but the reason was some javascript, I had working on the page...

Sorry. I did not recognize that!

Thanks a lot for your help.